# Content Query webpart and display list items from another subsite

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part

I have a portal homepage and subsites in this hierarchy

Home->Divisions->HR

I have created a custom list in HR subsite with Name, Department, Joining Date and City. Then I went to Home and added a Content Query web part and type was Query. Selected my custom list from HR site to display contents from.

Now i want to ask three things:

1. It does show items there but when I click on it it's not opening in modal dialog even though open as dialog is set in library settings.
2. It is only showing the first column value where I want to show 2 columns there
3. Column headers are not appearing.. just items are showing.

Answer (score 1):

For your 1. question: The library settings do *not* affect the items once they are opened from CQWP. The items' opening behavior is managed by the XSL Styling of the CQWP.

For your 2. question: Change the presentation of the CQWP to *Title and Description* for example. Then add as *Description* the column name you are willing to show such as `Modified`.

For 3.: Do you mean that column headers aren't appearing in the CQWP(**3.1**) or once the item is opened(**3.2)**?

3.1.: In the CQWP the column headers aren't visible due to the XSL Styling the web part uses. I'd suggest you to use Data View WP if its limitations don't matter in your case.

3.2.: If the column headers aren't visible once the item is opened, this is because of the *view* type. If you'd like to have column headers visible by default, you could change the default view to one that matches your needs.

Don't have a SP available right now, so can't test further your scenario :-(